# Django Forms: Avoid DB hit during import

Tags: python, django, django-forms, lazy-loading

I have this legacy django code:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    defaults={
        'foo': Foo.objects.get(id='...') 
        }
```

`Foo.objects.get()` is not lazy. This means the DB get connected during importing the python file.

This makes trouble in several places.

How to refactor this? Is there a lazy version of `Foo.objects.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to hit the database when instantiating the form.  I'd generally do that by overriding the constructor:

```
class FooForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.defaults = {
            'foo': Foo.objects.get(id='...') 
        }
```